# Printing function name and arguments in Node.js with debug

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to use [`debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) to be able to print method / function names and arguments on every call.

What's the best way to achieve this instead of placing customized `debug` statements in every function like this:

```
async function getFilePaths(path, id) {
  debug(`async function getFilePaths(path = ${path}, id = ${id})`);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: When writing an object to debug in Chrome it allows to view all it's properties

Comment: @AmirGeri this is server side JS - node

Comment: If you want to know where you are at a certain step, you can do `console.trace()`, though I only recommend using it in the console window.  I haven't tested with IE10+, but `console.trace()` and `console.debug()` broke IE 9 unless the developer window was open.

Comment: now that I see it's node.js, my comment is probably not related.

Comment: wrap your functions with a logging pass-through function

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function logDebug(fn, args) {
   debug(fn.name + args.toString());
}
```

And call it in your function

```
function getFilePaths(path, id) {
  logDebug(getFilePaths, arguments);
}
```

Note: `Function.name` is a new technology supported in ES6.

Comment: This is closer to what I want. `arguments.toString()` doesn't play well with debug, so it should be `Array.slice(arguments)`. However I still need to specify function name explicitly. Something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: You should not slice on arguments because it prevents optimizations in JavaScript engines (V8 for example). Instead, try constructing a new array by iterating through the arguments object. And you could try `function.caller` but it's not supported widely. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

Comment: This is for debugging purposes, so I'm not concerned about performance.  Using `debug` alone slows the whole thing down quite a lot.